# Not able to find inside the json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have one code to iterate the code and want the item of **product** by compare the **category** for example :
if category is "car" then product inside that array should be iterate with index not by name

**html**

```
<ul class="menulist"></ul>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**js**

```
var jsonData;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "product.json",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {

        },
        success: getData

    });

    function getData(data) {
        alert(data)
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


            var menulistdata = data[i].category,
                menulist = '<li class="" data-att="' + menulistdata + '">' + menulistdata + '</li>'
            $(".menulist").append(menulist);
        }


        $('.menulist li').on('click', function () {

            var list = $(this).text();

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(i)

                var productData = data[i].products;
                if (data[i].category == list) {
                    $(".content").append(productData.BMG[i].image + productData.BMG[i].date + productData.BMG[i].size);
                }



            }
        })
    }

});
```

**json**

```
[
    {
        "category":"car",
        "products": {
            "BMG" : [{
                "image" : "images/cars/BMW.jpg",
                "date": "5-May-2015",
                "type": "JPGE image",
                "size": "1132 KB"
            }],

            "verna":[{
                "image" : "images/cars/Verna.jpg",
                "date": "5-May-2015",
                "type": "JPGE image",
                "size": "1132 KB"
            }]
        }
    },

    {
        "category":"Nature",
        "products": {
            "Nature Mood At Night" : [{
                "image" : "images/nature/Night.jpg",
                "date": "5-May-2015",
                "type": "JPGE image",
                "size": "1132 KB"
            }],

            "Snowfall on Hut":[{
                "image" : "images/nature/Hut.jpg",
                "date": "5-May-2015",
                "type": "JPGE image",
                "size": "1132 KB"
            }]
        }
    }
]
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/3pgj0qv3/)

Comment: is `BMG` and `verna` `lenght` is same??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[0].products` is of type object – you cannot iterate over an object by indices, only by named keys. Use the **for..in statement** to iterate over an object.

```
for( var key in data[0].products ) {
    console.log( data[0].products[key] );
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: not able to get the desire result.. i want to iterate the indexing not by [0]..i appreciate if you can edit in my fiddle

Comment: and not able to find the image , size , type inside the array

Comment: @supersaiyan Wait what? You only have to replace the `0` with your increment variable `i`…

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to append all your car properties. So here is code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pgj0qv3/2/)

```
 $('.menulist li').on('click', function () {
            var list = $(this).text();
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var productData = data[i].products;
                if (data[i].category == list) {                    
                    for(z in productData){
                        for(x in productData[z][0]){                           
                        $(".content").append(productData[z][0][x])
                        }
                        $(".content").append('<br>')
                    }

                }

            }
        })
```